# Accessing Enviroment Variables in PHP Script while using suPHP

Tags: environment, suphp

I'm able to setup suPHP successfully and its running fine. But I'm facing a problem in accessing my environment variables which I was setting in /etc/init.d/httpd. Before using suPHP I was able to access them in my PHP scripts using variable order EGPCS option.

I do not want to use setEnv() inside my scripts because I have plenty of variables and changing them inside all the scripts is not what I'm liking.

Kindly suggest way to access these variables.

Thanks
Mohtashim